# Dual monitor setup for a MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2017, Two Thunderbolt 3 ports)

Tags: macbook-pro, display, usb

Is it possible to have a setup where you have:

- two non-mirrored external monitors (with maximum 2K resolution)
- eventually excluded built-in monitor (blank or lid closed)
- power supply
- single USB-2 with keyboard/mouse
- other USB-2 free

with my MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2017, Two Thunderbolt 3 ports)?

If so how can I do that more efficiently? And moreover what are the requirements that I have to satisfy while buying those two monitors?

---

It seems like two [Apple Multiport Adapters](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MJ1K2AM/A/usb-c-digital-av-multiport-adapter?fnode=8b&fs=fh%3D4595%252B3058) would potentially work, but the reviews don't seem to suggest that at all.

Comment: So, have you managed to find the desired setup? How does it look?

Comment: @Danijel 2 screens + 2 chep versions of [this](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MUF82AM/A/usb-c-digital-av-multiport-adapter?fnode=8b&amp;fs=fh%3D4595%252B3058) adapter. It's a joy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer is yes, long answer is it-depends...

Apple's adapters get very mixed reviews and are very expensive. You are better off looking for some 3rd party solutions. A couple of things to consider though...

What kind of interface for external displays

If you are looking at HDMI displays, make sure either both ends (your USB-C to HDMI adapter, and external monitor) support DHCP 2.2, or both ends doesn't. Most adapters you find on Amazon doesn't support this.

Reason why they don't support this is that DHCP is design for billions of colors and 4k, which will draw too much bandwidth from USB-C port, so you won't be able to connect anything else except power-input. Similar issue with mini-displayport adapters.

My personal recommendation is to use 2 external HDMI displays that doesn't require DHCP 2.2, in which case you can use 2 external USB-C hubs that supports HDMI, 2 USB-A, and 1 USB-C power-delivery for power input. As for which specific device, you may have to try a couple of them and find the best one for you. The few I've tried all failed for one reason or another, so I gave up on HDMI and went displayPort.

Another option to try, is that there are a few TB3 to 2-DP adapters. Then you can drive both displays using 1 port (assuming they both support displayPort), and do whatever you want with the other.